# Transform Future[Object] to Future[S]

Tags: scala

I'm struggling with composing Options and Futures. I have a method `find` that returns a `Future[Option[User]]` and I'm writing another function that calls this, does some stuff, and is then supposed to return another `Future[Option[User]]`. The problem is I can't quite get the signature right. Here's the methods:

```
def find(userID: BSONObjectID): Future[Option[User]]
def save(user: User): Future[User]
```

And what I'm trying to write:

```
def saveToken(token: String, id: BSONObjectID) = {
  userDAO.find(id).map {
    case Some(user) =>
      userDAO.save(user.copy(newToken = Some(token))).map(u => Some(u))
    case _ => None
  }
}
```

I think I almost have it. The issue is the signature is currently `Future[Object]` but I need it to be `Future[Option[User]]`. The idea is I want to add a `token` field to a user in my persistence layer only if I find the user. I want the method to return the `User` or `None` if the user didn't exist (identified by the `id`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with `case _` which returns an `Option` that doesn't match what `case Some(user)` returns.  To match their return type, make the default case return a `Future.successful(None)`, as shown in the following dummy example:

```
import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

case class User(name: String, newToken: Option[String])

val u1 = User("david", Some("t1"))
val u2 = User("rachel", Some("t2"))

List(Some(u1), Some(u2), None).map{
  case Some(user) => Future{ user.copy(newToken = Some("ok")) }.map(Some(_))
  case _ => None
}
// res1: List[Object] = List(Future(<not completed>), Future(<not completed>), None)

List(Some(u1), Some(u2), None).map{
  case Some(user) => Future{ user.copy(newToken = Some("ok")) }.map(Some(_))
  case _ => Future.successful(None)
}
// res2: List[scala.concurrent.Future[Option[User]]] = List(
//   Future(<not completed>), Future(<not completed>), Future(Success(None))
// )
```

Comment: Thanks this helps. I'm a little confused though. I thought that when I use `map` my result gets wrapped by a `Future[S]`. So why do I have to return a future in the `_` case? I would think it would do `Future[Future[Option[User]]]`. I actually ended up doing `flatMap` but followed your guidance to wrap `_` with a Future.

Comment: Glad that it helps.  You might be confused [Option's map](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.x/scala/Option.html#map[B](f:A=%3EB):Option[B]) which has a signature `def map[B](f: (A) => B): Option[B]`, with Future's map which is `def map[S](f: (T) => S)(implicit executor: ExecutionContext): Future[S]`.